# Converting a type containing string separated by periods into a nested object type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some string containing text separated by periods. There can be any number of periods, such as:

```
const stringX = "a.b";
const stringY = "a.b.c.d";
```

I want to use TypeScript to make some generic type `StringToNestedObject` that takes a string like that and outputs a type nested object type like:

```
type TypeX = StringToNestedObject<typeof stringX>;
// TypeX should be: { a: { b: string; } }

type TypeY = StringToNestedObject<typeof stringY>;
// TypeY should be: { a: { b: { c: { d: string; } } } }
```

The closest I can come up with for `StringToNestedObject` is:

```
type StringToNestedObject<S extends string> =
    S extends `${infer T}.${infer U}` ? {
        [T]: StringToNestedObject<U>
    } : {
        [S]: string
    };
```

but `[T]` and `[S]` don't actually work because:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.(1170)
> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)

[Here is a TypeScript playground with the above non-working code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAGjAvDARAQwDoAjHAbgChRJYFkUBNLXQog4AgEzPPKgE8ADgFMYAZShJUAFRAA5IdCEcA8kQBWQ4FAA8omEIAeUIWA4Q4EugD4s5GPbH6jJszAAGAEgDeyAGZD4GCkAXwJvPwCYAFVgtxgAfhgvOwdUgG0pAF0ALjFLaTkFYxV1TR0oqxT7YJhc5NT00RyLSRQqmGCKXkERKR6MbHFWmXlFEo0tbX5hEF8WujQrCgB6ZaD+uAALEABXABsOGCIhOpg8U6Jc2lRSDo6ead6exkH8lBGipVUJnUfZ+dQ9CW5FW62EjAg232h2Op3OSSOp2Apw4VzetxqmI6QA)

(Why do I want to do this? [IndexedDB key paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#key-path-construct) are string separated by periods which represent nested objects like this.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property path with template literal types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655728/property-path-with-template-literal-types) (it's not a perfect duplicate, but the question body and answer both seem to resolve your request pretty well)

Comment: Not directly since that's going in the opposite direction, but possibly something in that code will help me figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay maybe I should have played around a bit more before writing up a question :)

This works:

```
const stringX = "a.b";
const stringY = "a.b.c.d";

type StringToNestedObject<S extends string> =
    S extends `${infer T}.${infer U}` ? {[Key in T]: StringToNestedObject<U>} : {[Key in S]: string};

type TypeX = StringToNestedObject<typeof stringX>;
// TypeX should be: { a: { b: string; } }

type TypeY = StringToNestedObject<typeof stringY>;
// TypeY should be: { a: { b: { c: { d: string; } } } }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAGjAvDARAQwDoAjHAbgChRJYFkUBNLXQog4AgEzPPKgE8ADgFMYAZShJUAFRAA5IdCEcA8kQBWQ4FAA8omEIAeUIWA4Q4EugD4s5GPbH6jJszAAGAEgDeyAGZD4GCkAXwJvPwCYAFVgtxgAfhgvAG0AaSE+GGQggF0ALjFLaTkFYxV1TR0oq2CYApT0zOzRfItJFGCKXkERKR6MbHF2mXlFco0tbX5hEF82ujQrCgB6ZaD+uAALEABXABsOGCIhepg8U6IC2lRSGFrgnmnensZBopQR0qVVCZ0n2fmqHoS3Iq3WwkYEG2+0Ox1O5ySR1OwFOHCu71u9zudyAA)