# Typescript: paths of all parents of leaves

Tags: typescript, recursion, tree, key, inferred-type

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object) post is already covering how to get all paths of leaves of an object. I'm using this

```ts
type DotPrefix<T extends string> = T extends '' ? '' : `.${T}`;

/**
 * Extracts paths of all terminal properties ("leaves") of an object.
 */
export type PropertyPath<T> = (
  T extends object
    ? {
        [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]: `${K}${DotPrefix<PropertyPath<T[K]>>}`;
      }[Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]
    : ''
) extends infer D
  ? Extract<D, string>
  : never;
```

which is based on this [#66661477](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655728/property-path-with-template-literal-types/66661477#66661477) answer. But now I need to pull all those paths up by one level. That is, instead of picking `"album.track.id"` in

```ts
interface Track {
  album: {
    track: {
      id: string
    }
  }
}
```

I need to pick `"album.track"` which is the path of the parent of the leaf `"album.track.id"`.

How can it be done? If you know the leaves' keys, you can do this:

```ts
type ParentPath<
  T,
  P extends PropertyPath<T>,
  K extends string
> = P extends `${infer Head}.${K}` ? Head : never;
```

(which should be improved by constraining `K` to `keyof ...`), but what if I don't want to pass the key? The problem is, with setting `K` to `string`, `Head` will be inferred as the string up to the *first* `"."`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6VG6w) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that would work for me. I would appreciate it if you could write up an answer, thanks.

Comment: sure, will do soon

Answer (score 0):

Can you see anything wrong with this:?

```ts
export type ParentPath<T> = {
  [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]: T[K] extends object
    ? `${K}${DotPrefix<ParentPath<T[K]>>}`
    : '';
}[Exclude<keyof T, symbol>] extends infer D
  ? Extract<D, string>
  : never;
```

It's just like `PropertyPath`, only is it ignoring keys of non-object-like properties...

Answer (score 0):

Arguments:

- `T` - The type that we  traverse
- `P extends PropertyPath<T>` - The path to the leaf property
- `AccP extends string = ''` - The accumulative path of already traversed properties.

The logic:

- Check whether `P` is in the shape of `{keyOfT}.${RestOfThePath}`

  - If not, return `never`
  - Else if there is a `.` in the `RestOfThePath`

    - If the RestOfThePath is the property path of the `T[keyOfT]`

      - Call the `PropertyPath` recursively for the `T[keyOfT]` and append `.${keyOfT}` to the `AccP`
    - Return `never`
  - If there is not `.` then return `${AccP}.${keyofT}`

Implementation:

```
type ParentPath<
  T,
  P extends PropertyPath<T>,
  AccP extends string = '',
> = P extends `${infer Head extends keyof T &
  string}.${infer Rest extends string}`
  ? Rest extends `${string}.${string}`
    ? Rest extends PropertyPath<T[Head]>
      ? ParentPath<T[Head], Rest, AccP extends '' ? Head : `${AccP}.${Head}`>
      : never
    : `${AccP}.${Head}`
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
//  "album.track"
type Test = ParentPath<Track, 'album.track.id'>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9sACgJwgMwJYA8A8AVKCLYCAOwBMBnKS4ZDUgcwD4oBeKAoki6gcj5QA-FAFQAXFAAGAOgAkAbzwBfKQG4AUBoD0AKl0aouqAFFiyAIYBjYNTAXgAC2pw0UCwBsPUEsgC2DJ5QYMhwkMjAGBDUABQARB4QFgBu0XEAlFCu7qRZAEYAVhA2Moa62hpEYHARPuDQKGEQESCIDo74rBwxhpyExGRU+UU2vVDCUApj4zMA2gDSUAymWFYeAK7kEDgA1hAg2XgANDQgfnlwHswAupJSivPKivBIqJi4jeGgbU74C9fMZiqTQzGbKWZmNabbZ7A5uY6nc6XG7TSQCDSZbiDagMNDNWC9ERmOjWYA4GAnWj0JjMXqSUgQVLITQaUCQKBtVCkJDtHC9Y69RD9HhDT7Nb68vDMI69ACCVisQqxvBodAYjHYoj4Mq6HOF2Okilx+IAEklyPqVbDDlAAGS9Knq5TyBTG5BQABK0WAlqGjqYqkJnu9vuo9wU-sYzsUkcDoJEXtooY5oS+rUlszNFnIAOm4xEnLIPN+eEz5uuJ0TwBO8sVybEIizFruilriGjCibqlpoPG9MZzVRhoUbY7XakdKgDKZLIYvjQ1mgeEsVh2k16njy6z8kimoJJq93eaW5EkkZBYIvyk0yi0bKXIY4he5Pw6y+sOxOfE325kB52MgYOQfDMJoQA)