# Extract nested type by condition while tracking deep path

Tags: typescript

Given the following object structure:

```
type IObject = { id: string, path: string, children?: IObject[] }

const tree = [
    {
      id: 'obj1' as const,
      path: 'path1' as const,
      children: [
        {
          id: 'obj2' as const,
          path: ':pathParam' as const,
          children: [
            {
              id: 'obj3' as const,
              path: 'path3' as const
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 'obj4' as const,
          path: 'path4' as const,
          children: [
            {
              id: 'obj5' as const,
              path: 'path5' as const
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I am trying to extract the type of a nested object PLUS the an accumulation of the `path` fragments to that nested type. (assuming ids are unique across the object)
example

```
type ok = FindAndTrackDeepPath<'obj2', typeof tree>['fullPath'];
// type ok = "/path1/:pathParam"
```

I tried the following which i think is close. However, as you can see in the second (non working) example, there seems to be an issue when descending the type recursively.

```
export type FindAndTrackDeepPath<
  ID,
  T extends IObject[],
  depth extends number = 1,
  path extends string = '',
  maxDepth extends number = 10
> = depth extends maxDepth
  ? never
  : FindByID<ID, T> extends never
    ? FindAndTrackDeepPath<
        ID,
        Descend<T>['children'],
        Increment<depth>,
        Descend<T>['path'] extends undefined ? '' : `${path}/${Descend<T>['path']}`
      >
    : FindByID<ID, T> & { fullPath: `${path}/${FindByID<ID, T>['path']}` };


// helpers
type FindByID<ID, T extends IObject[]> = Extract<T[number], { id: ID }>;
type Descend<T extends IObject[]> = Extract<T[number], { children: IObject[] }>;
type Increment<N extends number> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,...number[]][N];

// examples
type ok = FindAndTrackDeepPath<'obj2', typeof tree>['fullPath'];
// type ok = "/path1/:pathParam"
type notOK = FindAndTrackDeepPath<'obj3', typeof tree>['fullPath'];
// type notOK = "/path1/:pathParam/path3" | "/path1/path4/path3"
```

`type notOK` has two alternatives, one of which is obviously wrong.

I think the problem is that when descending recursively a union of all options at each level is created in a "breadth first" kind of way. (i.e. somthing like this happens: ${("/path1/:pathParam" | "/path1/path4")}/path3"})
I have tried several ways to further prune unsuccessful descends/"parts of the unions" while descending. To no avail.

I have found a few related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655728/property-path-with-template-literal-types) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object/76732921#76732921). These, however, extract all possible paths. Instead i want to only extract the path for a child type matching specific criteria (in my case `extends { id: ID}`).

Can anyone help me out here? Is this even possible?

[TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgeQEYCsoGMQwLwwN4wCWAJgFwwDOIAToQHYDmANDBAIYgAW5VtjL6ToQA2xalDoB+colQYQAbQC6MAL7Bg6APZ0qMGlFi4FwGGfynzZkuQDkW1AEZbMNhRjbdIJpavsudv6czq7unlQ+VmaCImIS5CZR5ni+SURkMPaoAEwubh46EalJQXakQQAKbNRsALZ5YYXexVExouJ0CS1JKWlpNpkOKADMDQVekX1RpZlBo6HjVN1R6lMwSsuqkz3L1hlZKAAsY+HNazO2QccLp9tpbXGdMIlrFq-mAwcArCdNd+ccbizQE-G5NXbmVZTDZ9KFWGGQyxKADcGigAA8IFpqFhwNAYAAxejEACCdGIABUaugANYAEUMECqXAAPJY4HTJhSYBiQBJiO5ZGhMMpJsQoBAuDz0Xzye46ABXWpIKDUHAwRyTILS2UCyg0egMdW2WyTWpsdEMyWcHX8+VKlVq3COAAMwAAfOrxdbbXKYObLRKuJZJDA6FAAG6qyzkInkgBCYA5LI5LApnt5drDkejVlDcdJ5KpbFpDIlzM4bL6qeWDIo6H5LPTClsDw6tiU-3McDo6HEtQkIBZ3q47q7ZjrDfJTfdLaCHd9eoV5KgADN6FBiDBQyaYOQAAYAEjwQVUAHpj5PG83LoCO6p9y13alY8TE8nUzB0zAAGT4GCrgqwjCBWB7HqeF54AW750imnJfrOt5cPe+5qKiGhnmeMCcFAwjQNQFCgJAsDQUmsGftymZ+kK8jKJ6uAAKIytSQ4UgoirKqqnb-gMHJqO6qJ4rAV7TpRMpZjRIpKPRMBMTQJasexDpcSwBBtvE8DIMKigqKoAlEfiPZ9lAA50EOAByi72px1AyQomrZEwwxMIcTBfEwABsTAAOxMAAHEwACcTCuiFmqOI5AB00UcY6yhKAo5kohhWEYnUEDCFAhFCTAWg0uqBZkpS1L0oyFYsgcuQsEJWirvo4hQIhgHARWHaoph+jEbl+W4AARGeQSOGe5SAlUNS1L1BmwHQWggAgADSBXEkVxalmVgIVUMozVcRtX1YYTVASBd7JR1OUzXNi19QNgJDSNXBjXUN1cMMvUwAAPjA-WDc9nCHL9r1AA)

Comment: path and id are both optional. I suggest: let's leave it as is (path and id not optional), and i will follow-up with a question on how to do it with optional path + id. ack?

Comment: Okay so then [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wR17LW) is the final one for this question?  Please give me a clear yes/no so I can know how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: yes, this one. it is the answer to the question as i initially put it. thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I will write up the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I changed the implementation slightly to make it a little easier to explain and so that it doesn't hinge on `id` or `path` being keylike... that doesn't mean `id` and `path` can be missing without any modification, but it's hopefully easier to adapt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation of what I'm calling `IdxWithFullPath<I, T>`, where `I` is the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `id` type you're looking for inside of the `IObject`-or-`IObject[]` `T` type.  It will evaluate to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the `IObject` that has an `id` assignable to type `I`, and an object with a `fullPath` property corresponding to the concatenation of all the `path` properties in the tree from the root down to the `IObject` in question:

```
type IdxWithFullPath<I, T, P extends string = ""> =
  T extends IObject[] ? IdxWithFullPath<I, T[number], P> :
  T extends IObject ? (
    I extends T["id"] ? (
      T & { fullPath: `${P}/${T["path"]}` }
    ) : (
      IdxWithFullPath<I, T["children"], `${P}/${T["path"]}`>
    )
  ) :
  never;
```

There's a third generic type parameter `P` corresponding to the parent path; this allows `IdxWithFullPath` to be recursive.  It [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to the empty string literal type, the path of the root of the tree.

Note that it is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in `T`.  That means if `T` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then it will be split into individual members which will be processed separately, and the results will be joined back into a union.  Since [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) gets absorbed into unions, that means we can just return `never` for anything we don't want to include.

So, if `T` is an array of `IObject`s, then we want to operate instead on `T[number]`, the union of `IObject` element types.

Otherwise, if `T` is an `IObject`, we check its `id` property.  If it matches `I` then we return the desired intersection, where the `fullPath` is the parent path stored in `P` concatenated with the `path` property of the current `IObject`, using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types). If it *doesn't* match `I` then we have to recurse down into `children`, appending `path` to `P` to be the new parent path.

And finally, if `T` is something else then we return `never` so that it's not included in the result.  This will happen when the search bottoms out, such as with a missing `children` property: I think if `children` is missing, then `T["children"]` will evaluate to `unknown`, and when `children` is present but `undefined` then `T["children"]` will evaluate to `undefined`.  We want neither of those to be included.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type Ok = IdxWithFullPath<'obj2', typeof tree>;
/* type Ok = {
    id: "obj2";
    path: ":pathParam";
    children: {
        id: "obj3";
        path: "path3";
    }[];
} & {
    fullPath: "/path1/:pathParam";
} */

type AlsoOK = IdxWithFullPath<'obj3', typeof tree>;
/* type AlsoOK = {
    id: "obj3";
    path: "path3";
} & {
    fullPath: "/path1/:pathParam/path3";
} */
```

---

Looks good.  Note that such deeply recursive conditional types tend to have bizarre edge cases that sometimes require significant refactoring in order to resolve.  With any such type, you should test heavily against expected use cases before proceeding, and be prepared to have to modify or even abandon an approach if you find unacceptably bad edge case behavior.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GAAAwAJHhyqoAPQRp2coJu1QhuFRACUMHINt6cAx2LxgaVKsdztu7TobpY4cjMbjzsTSmTPNSaYsGYNZjoUAAbtqkaBILAEABrDm52UFxVTUnvbI2FgoqBaP36cRQHlI6MAKn0g5gI45PVe1k5mSynKRk38XLKU0q1RqF9SZbi5CPvR2p6GT7+14TU0GH9lmUJFVBgH1339Qtg05aMggcaNby4e9aifMCt2jZE9wAQWECgtAQABpMc8zlBUgzJWdhgXQdl1XQwN2Abdd1RXD8KIw9Uk-TJAMvSxTn-LheOAMCINSAMpz-OCpgQpDOBQmppKEtCYAwoA)