# Type for a dot separated path to type

Tags: typescript

I want to strongly type a dot separated path to a specific type. Let's say we have a recursive structure where every leaf is a specific type, in this case translations by a set of languages:

```
type Language = "pl" | "en";

type Translation = { [ lang in Language ]: string };
type Translations = { [key: string]: Translation | Translations | undefined };
```

An example of this might be:

```
const translations = {
  hello: {
    pl: "Dzieńdobry",
    en: "Hello",
  },
  bool: {
    yes: {
      pl: "Tak",
      en: "Yes",
    },
    no: {
      pl: "Nie",
      en: "No",
    },
  },
};
```

I want a type for the paths: `"hello"`, `"bool.yes"` and `"bool.no"`, but *not* to `"bool"` or `"missing"` or `"bool.foo" or` "hello.pl"`. Here's what I have so far:

For a single layered translations file:

```
type KeyToTranslation<T extends Translations, K extends string = string> = K extends keyof T 
  ? T[K] extends Translation
    ? K
    : never
  : never;

function printTranslationByKey<T extends Translations, K extends string>(
  t: T,
  k: KeyToTranslation<T, K>
) {
    console.log(t[k]);
}
printTranslationByKey(translations, "hello"); // Valid, Correct!
printTranslationByKey(translations, "hello.pl"); // Error, Correct!
printTranslationByKey(translations, "missing"); // Error, Correct!
printTranslationByKey(translations, "bool.yes"); // Error, Incorrect.
```

So we need some template strings and `infer`s. Unfortunately I can't seem to get this working. It seems to forget that I've already asserted that `T[TKey] extends Translations`:

```
type DeepKeyToTranslation<T extends Translations, K extends string = string> =  K extends keyof T
    ? T[K] extends Translation
        ? K
        : never
    :
      // This is where we extend this further to cover the dot separated case:
      
      K extends `${infer TKey}.${infer Rest}`
        ? TKey extends keyof T
            ? T[TKey] extends undefined
                ? never
                : T[TKey] extends Translations
                    ? Rest extends DeepKeyToTranslation<T[TKey], Rest>
                        ? K
                        : never
                    : never
            : never
        : never;

function printTranslationByDeepKey<T extends Translations, K extends string>(
  t: T,
  k: DeepKeyToTranslation<T, K>
) {
    console.log(t[k]);
}
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "hello"); // Good!
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "hello.pl"); // Error
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "missing"); // Error
```

It fails because:

```
Type 'T[TKey]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Translations'.
  Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'Translations'.
    Type 'Translation | Translations | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Translations'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Translations'.()
```

I've found several other similar questions:

- [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object)
- [Generic function to get a nested object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64575901/generic-function-to-get-a-nested-object-value/64578478#64578478)

The second was even the base for my current implementation, but neither provide a similar function where you can stop recursion based on the type of the value at the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure the `| undefined` part of your `Translations` type is needed (might be wrong here), and I suspect that's what causing most of the trouble.

I slightly reworked your example and got to a point that seems to be working, have a look at it and see if it covers your use case!

```js
type Language = "pl" | "en";

type Translation = { [lang in Language]: string };
type Translations = { [key: string]: Translation | Translations };

type DeepKeyToTranslation<T extends Translations, K extends string = string> = K extends keyof T
    ? T[K] extends Translation
        ? K
        : never
    : K extends `${infer TKey}.${infer Rest}`
        ? T[TKey] extends Translations
            ? DeepKeyToTranslation<T[TKey], Rest> extends never
                ? never
                : K
            : never
        : never

declare function printTranslationByDeepKey<T extends Translations, K extends string>(
    t: T,
    k: DeepKeyToTranslation<T, K>
): K

const translations = {
    hello: {
        pl: "Dzieńdobry",
        en: "Hello",
    },
    bool: {
        yes: {
            pl: "Tak",
            en: "Yes",
        },
        no: {
            pl: "Nie",
            en: "No",
        },
    },
    nested: {
        deep: {
            ok: {
                pl: "Dzieńdobry",
                en: "Hello",
            }
        }
    }
};


printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "hello") // ok
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "bool.yes") // ok
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "hello.pl") // err
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "missing") // err
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "nested.deep.ok") // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=56&ssc=58&pln=26&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5OgXigIjAGxygB9cIEcBuAKGtEigBUAnRAZ3zmAEsB7BKNgDeUANqdkUbgPjI0GALoAuKG2DNpSKAF8a9aC3ace-NoKgjRAawggVajcmVNWCDlz4DSht8c9ndWn0oABEICDAAaVtGXh93EwQAHkYoCAAPYHIAEzN4v1MAGihItMycswdNcyrkAD5zUoyshFyoGxBeADMmaih+qAB+JlFIhTKWtvyPfj6B+eHIufn+lQQIADcIZmWoFSby1rMAAwASIWku7aZokG0AOnPL64AlCDVtY92FkcZb8eaFRcRhmbm+K36wzCEVusWmiRSoj+tgUxTeagagKOUHWWx2EIJA2GuO24MJqxKZJWa02pMJNLxtGyEAAxpxmNAuigECzElAwI5gPDPAAhEDQqK2FITIHCoolGXY2pIOoACl2wBUjEKuysKglsLirgSnhSxUidWoAEp9rQ7SzTMAoOoQYkzMJdgALCD4fC8FRCKkEFQ4EIAL24EEAIoDZXgAI2YIBwOsJ5BDAAkfX7k7ttCmBnHeLx8AGqSB3qXyQNg7hGHArDmq-007gAJrvRsEvNUhD+ixU+Y1nAAOUjnarLZHvHHK278znA3Wagg2UrBOZETXVd4ev7TZWQ-DkZj8cTM-3k8zvun+ar2ip9-n1ECtAF0iFxoKCDFBtsqpdvigmwxQ4N6144Fa1BvggH6uqK4rhJKID-p+QEgYWxb3OWbAQVBgpyt+CEwn+AEmvKoFZrw9wELh0GwYBiQ-ohtwoXB5EALbcGwbCaLR+GoYxRFIaxDH+CBS5ZNk9wbmA9w7rh1BAA)

Comment: Drives me nuts that typescript doesn't recognize that a given path might be undefined, I was trying to avoid something that I think you're right doesn't matter if I only use `Translations` as a type constraint rather than an actual type... `const x: Translations = ...`

Comment: This got me to the insight I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this solution:

```js
type Language = "pl" | "en";


const translations = {
  hello: {
    pl: "Dzieńdobry",
    en: "Hello",
  },
  bool: {
    yes: {
      pl: "Tak",
      en: "Yes",
    },
    no: {
      pl: "Nie",
      en: "No",
    },
  },
} as const;

type Translations = typeof translations;

type KeysUnion<T, Cache extends string = ''> =
  T extends PropertyKey ? Cache : keyof T extends Language ? Cache : {
    [P in keyof T]:
    P extends string
    ? Cache extends ''
    ? KeysUnion<T[P], `${P}`>
    : Cache | KeysUnion<T[P], `${Cache}.${P}`>
    : never
  }[keyof T]

type Result = KeysUnion<Translations>

function printTranslationByDeepKey<T extends Translations, K extends KeysUnion<Translations>>(
  t: T,
  k: K
) {}
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "hello"); // Good!
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "hello.pl"); // Error
printTranslationByDeepKey(translations, "missing"); // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5OgXigIjAGxygB9cIEcBuAKFoGMB7BAZ2CmACdFn85gBLJsyjYA3tShQAFhHz4GALijjJkgkpwARAF78IgEUAAJgwBGHEDgA0E1eQ0AJWfKs2AvtckmGDfEpWqQCGY-G1UodVwAFTgAaxcwyTtcAE0g+NV3UKgERWUstV9cADk9dLCknCKGMqhMyUzXKDhhRhZgGmpQSChIrhZeASERdnAIBgAzdj6ePkEWDq7oAGkIEGYAVQQ5gB5IyygAYTg6GSgIAA9gckNhVg5+ZGGAcieAPhEbSLPL6+EABQ4DEgHFAKxAUAA-IdjqclDFVhMet8rggbrBEKh0NAoUcTtAQmEANp-KAPKDwkCIyIAXQUWRJFxRaLuDyQWRxMOgjN+UBe7KgYI2WyYu2J1P2AAMACSiP6uCWvLJKXGnUiCzY7SJiyUylUQVwAOhlcoVSuyEAAbhAOG5CRSqdTaIsoAAlIIofBsbDq4UIXbTAZzZiK6jjFAIOiDBDhe4IYC9biBpgAIRAmggEDAYN2yJ5Cf6syE+yWudRwh9moDhZYr1eAAobMAlHsbDElEtqABKZSuahgWPxqtR1PpzNguucRPV5j7HAyOTVTuUKAAehXUAA4t5DABCPsD-MzYdpjNZ1YTodB2fz+QGgg4Jer9cAUQ4gJt-Yeg6nx9HZ5AF4-leuAALb8MwzCsg+y5rlAr7vkAA)

**`KeysUnion`** - recursively iterates through `Translations` type.
If `Cache extends ""` - it means that it is first iteration and we need to call `KeysUnion` recursively with approperiate arguments but without using `Cache` memoization, since it makes no sense to have an empty string in a result.
If `Cache` is not an empty string, apply `Cache` to result (unionize it with result) and call `KeysUnion<T[P],` ${Cache}.${P}`>` with new suffix.

`T extends PropertyKey` - if `T` is no more object - return `Cache`
`keyof T extends Language` - if `T` is an object with `pl/en` keys - no need to  apply them to result - return `Cache`.

You can find another one explanation of this utility type with comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668055/eliminate-nevers-to-make-union-possible/68672512?noredirect=1#comment121362429_68672512)

You can find much more explanation in my [blog](https://catchts.com/deep-pick)

List of related answers: [ [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242871/declare-a-type-that-allows-all-parts-of-all-levels-of-another-type#answer-67247652), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type#answer-69129328), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449511/get-typescript-to-infer-tuple-parameters-types/69450150#69450150), [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449511/get-typescript-to-infer-tuple-parameters-types/69450150#69450150) ]

Comment: Right. I specifically want the recursion to stop when it hits an object with whatever shape I hand it. Translations aren't the only use case here. And I can totally see cases where the keys of the object in question are legitimate higher in the tree than the leaves. For example `"translations.languages.pl"` with `en` and `pl` keys for how to say 'Polish' in English (Polish) and Polish (Polski).