# Create a function that accepts a strictly-typed object path as argument

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this type:

```
type SomeType = {
  propA: {
    propA1: {
      propA12: string;
    };
    propA2: string;
  };
  propB: {
    propB1: string;
    propB2: {
      propB12: string;
      propB22: string;
    };
  };
};
```

How can I define a function that could receive a string with any combination of a valid path for `SomeType` and have the compiler check that?

I mean, I want to have a function `doSomething` that I could call like this:

```
doSomething('propA.propA1')
doSomething('propA')
doSomething('propB.propB2.propB12')
```

but never like this:

```
doSomething('propA.propB')
doSomething('propB.propA1')
doSomething('propA.propA2.propA12')
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69667244/3001761, or the questions it links to?

Comment: You could do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/WYKjgN). See linked q/a for more info.

Comment: This is awesome! This answers my question perfectly, so thank you both!